# Python error for index in print string for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My code is here. I am new

what is wrong?

Comment: Almost all programming languages indexes start with 0 and last this makes last element n-1'th

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, for a string you also have position 0,
what you should be doing is looping from 0,7 and then it should output properly.

```
str = 'abcdefg'
for i in range(0,7):
    print(str[i])
```

Comment: In case you didnt know, a is positions 0, b 1, c 2, and so on. This is how it is for strings, lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like many programming languages, index starts from 0 on python.
So your code must be:

```
str = 'abcdefg'
for i in range(0,7):
    print(str[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is already mentioned, in programming, indexing starts at `0`. In your code above, having `range` from `1` to `8` means that you start from the second element (that is `b`) until the ninth element (which does not exists as your string has a length of `7`, from `0` to `6` and thus the error). If you want to print all characters in the string, Python has a built-in [`len`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp) function which takes a variable as an argument and prints its length. So taking into consideration that indexing starts at `0` and the `len` function, you could modify your `range` function as following:

```
str = 'abcdefg'
for i in range(0,len(str)):
    print(str[i])
```

**Note**: By convention, when your starting value in range function is `0`, you can omit it and write only the end value:

```
for i in range(len(str)):
```

Same goes for the `step` argument, if it's equal to `1`. You can read more about `range` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

Keep in mind that [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) is a reserved Python keyword and you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
str = 'abcdefg'
for i in range(7):
    print(str[i])
```

OR

```py
str = 'abcdefg'
for i in range(len(str)):
    print(str[i])
```

OR

```py
str = 'abcdefg'
for i in str:
    print(i)
```

Be careful, you'd better not use str as a variable name.